# Install ipa from my server in a jailbroken device with out user interaction

Tags: ios, installation, hook, jailbreak

I need to install my application(.ipa) in a **jailbroken** device with out user interaction.

- This installation has to be triggered by an other application which is already installed in that device.
- My .ipa is in a sever, So is it possible to install through `itms://` or is there any jailbroken alternative available
- I want to install this app silently **(with out MDM)**, there should not be "**Install**" "**Cancel**" alert popping for the user to select.
- Let me know if there is a possibility of achieving this through `%hook`.

Comment: Did u find solutioin?

Comment: yep. but it was long time back. i will try to recollect and add the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to my above question**

Each step below has literally 100 more steps internally. If you are not familiarized with jailbroken apps/tools development, this is going to be a nightmare. Sorry, I cannot share code since I did it for a client. but stack overflow has answers for how to do the various components i mentioned below separately. once you do a little POC on separate components, my answer will help you to put them together.

> This will work only in jailbroken devices and cracked ipa files

1. Create a daemon application.
2. make sure it runs 24/7 in background.
3. To trigger installation from server, add socket.io(or any other
   similar framework) to the app (since daemon app is running always,
   make sure the socket connection to the server is also always alive)
4. Send the URL of zipped ipa file to daemon app via socket.io server.
5. In the daemon app, unzip the .zip to .ipa
6. once it is unzipped there are two ways you can install the app.
7. easy way is to unzip .ipa further to .app and move .app folder to the
   applications folder in iPhone.
8. There is a private springboard api, which takes ipa file path as
   input and installs it

> If you cannot crack the ipa

This is way more complex than above :) you have to run a code which opens AppStore, Search for the application and install it.

1. same as above upto step 3
2. Manually(for POC) record the coordinates of all the button clicks inside AppStore required to install any app in general. like click on search tab at the bottom, select the search bar, insert text in search bar, click on search button, click get/install button from result....
3. create a dynamic library which takes those coordinates as an input and do a uiautomation. inject this dynamic library into AppStore.
4. from the server, send this coordinates to your daemon application, which will pass on this coordinates to dynamic library and open AppStore from background.
5. once AppStore is opened, beauty of dynamic library is, it will kick in automatically and start you ui automation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try and let you know if I succeeded. I'm doing local build and distributing system for my team. Devs push to git repo, unity 3d + xcode build ipa file, then I need to push and launch ipa on our devices.

Comment: great! please note that, all the above stuffs is for jailbroken iPhone not for a regular one. if you want it in regular iPhone, then instead of a background daemon application you need a normal application(call it as admin app) which opens your new apps through URL schema and once your new app is up and done with its work, you can call back the admin app through URL. in that way you can keep the admin app alive and connected with socket.io  24/7.

Comment: Installing a new ipa in a regular phone programmatically may be a issue though! one possible direction would be, Xcode can install application on connected (wifi/cable) phones. so theoretically you can write a script and run it in a mac machine which does exactly what Xcode does.